# How can I return the value of a specific attribute in an XML column for all rows in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, xpath, xquery

So I've spent all day looking for good examples of using xpath / xquery as part of a SQL Server query to return values from an XML data column to no avail.

Here's what I'm trying to do. I have the following XML in a XML data column in a table:

```
<Document ID="156">
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <LastModifiedInVersion>1.0</LastModifiedInVersion>
  <Signatures />
  <Controls>
    <Control ID="TB1">
      <Value>Hello world!</Value>
    </Control>
  </Controls>
  <AutoKeys />
</Document>
```

I'm trying to write a SQL Server query that will return the value of the `ID` attribute of the `Document` node. I want to do this for all of the rows in the table, and all the XML data starts in the exact same format.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I really just need a clean example and I can take it from there!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that's the whole XML in your table's XML column??

In that case, use something like this:

```
SELECT
   (list of other columns),
   XmlColumn.value('(/Document/@ID)[1]', 'int') AS 'DocumentID'
FROM
   dbo.YourTable
```

The `.value()` call basically takes an XPath as its first parameter, and a T-SQL type as its second parameter, and returns that XML value as the given T-SQL datatype to your query.

Comment: I seem to recall you can't grab attributes off the root element.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: are you sure??? it does work just fine in SQL Server 2008 R2 (Mgmt Studio) on my machine.... try it!

Comment: Well others are much larger but for the moment all I care about is getting the value of the ID attribute.

Thank you so much! I was so close, I had my closing parenthesis in the wrong place. I'm totally new to xpath / xquery but have some experience in SQL so this will be great getting me started!

Comment: Hmm good to know.  I just remember having some frustrations with that some time ago, I have not tried it recently.

Comment: @Xedicon: SQL Server XQuery is a bit special in this case here for the `.value()` call in that you have to make sure to select just a single node (that's the reason for the `[1]` at the end of the XPath expression).

Answer (score 1):

If your xml is saved in the database as a normal string, convert and query it instantly

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, [XMLStringColumn]).value('(/Document/@ID)[1]', 'int') 
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT xmlcol.value('(//Document/@ID)[1]','int') AS DocID  FROM xmltable
```